# Using comboboxes

Tags: excel, vba

How can I get all the cell values(eg. dates) found in a row(A1, B1, C1, and so on) and put it in a combobox?

I tried this but no luck:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
   With Worksheets("Sheet1")
       ComboBox1.List = .Range("A1:Z" & .Range("A" & .Columns.Count).End(xlRight).Column).Value
    End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: your attempt to get the last column is close but not quite right.  Change to `ComboBox1.List = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").end(xltoright)).Value`  This may or may not be your issue.

Comment: @ScottCraner very close, but needs transpose to convert row to column. Plus better to look back from far right to left.

Comment: @brettdj, yeah I got hung up on the range issue that I forgot it needed to be transposed.  And normally I do go from the far right but I wanted to match as close as possible the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

Although you may want to work further with the range to remove blanks, dupes etc

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
Dim rng1 As Range
With Sheets(1)
Set rng1 = .Range([a1], Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(rng1.Value)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @progRAImmer you should mark this answer as correct, there is a green check mark just below the down arrow that only you can mark.